# How to delete all lines containing certain keywords in a txt file with python

Tags: python

How to delete all lines containing certain keywords in a txt file with python.

I have a txt file with 10000’s of data. I want to delete any line containing "2021–07-13"

The data is represented like this (this is just an example, the data it self has thousands of the same date data):

```
{“date”:”2021-08-13T15:13:49.752Z”, ”value”:”184478”}
{“date”:”2021-08-13T15:13:49.752Z”, ”value”:”128478”}
{“date”:”2021-08-13T15:13:49.752Z”, ”value”:”183478”}
{“date”:”2021-08-13T15:13:49.752Z”, ”value”:”188478”}
{“date”:”2021-08-13T15:13:49.752Z”, ”value”:”188478”}
{“date”:”2021–07-13T15:13:49.752Z”, ”value”:”18658”}
{“date”:”2021-07-13T15:13:49.752Z”, ”value”:”184478”}
{“date”:”2021-07-13T15:13:49.752Z”, ”value”:”128478”}
{“date”:”2021-06-13T15:13:49.752Z”, ”value”:”183478”}
{“date”:”2021-06-13T15:13:49.752Z”, ”value”:”188478”}
{“date”:”2021-05-13T15:13:49.752Z”, ”value”:”188478”}
{“date”:”2021–0513T15:13:49.752Z”, ”value”:”18658”}
```

Comment: what problem do you face?

Comment: I want to delete any line containing "2021–0713"

Comment: We work on bugs, which means we need the code you've already written. Also, is this some standard format? It looks kinda like json but the quotes are wrong.

Comment: You could just delete the entire text file (see [`iff`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iff)) ;)

Comment: Change your last line too... 2021–0513T15

Answer (score 3):

Open your file, read line one by one, keep only right lines and write to a new file:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as inp, open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    for line in inp:
        if '2021–07-13' not in line:
            out.write(line)
```

Enhanced by @tdelaney: remove `readlines` and use file object instead.

Comment: I think writing to another file is a good idea. It is safer than writing to same file in case something goes wrong in the loop.

Comment: @Unsel. `readlines` returns an iterator so the file is not loaded into memory. I think you can have an unexpected result on a large file.

Comment: @Corralien - readlines returns a list. A list can be iterated of course, but you have consumed the entire file and put it in memory when readlines is done.

Comment: Thank you for your input Corralien. Don't worry I have a copy of the file, so it's not a problem

Comment: @tdelaney. You're right! I'm really disappointed!!!

Comment: @MmVictory - Did you use the same file name for both opens? That second open deletes any existing file with the same name. There likely shoule be a rename of output to input file when the loop is done.

Comment: @MmVictory. Can you explain why the file has been corrupted/deleted/overwritten, please?

Comment: @Corralien - not a problem. Just make it `for line in inp:` and you're good.

Comment: @tdelaney. Do you know a mean to get an iterator rather than a list?

Comment: @Corralien - the file object will iterate the lines in the file. `for line in inp: ` will do it.

Comment: You could even leverage writelines to get rid of the for loop. After opening the files, a one-liner is `out.writelines(line for line in inp if '2021–07-13' not in line)`

Answer (score 1):

```py
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if '2021-0713' not in line.strip("\n"):
            f.write(line)
```

Comment: @Corralien strip() does not mutate the string it operates on, just returns a value

Comment: You don't need the strip operation - it doesn't matter if there is a \n at the end for the compare. Its harmless, but not needed.

Comment: My bad sorry!!!